# sql, javax.persistence.criteria: check a database table column with comma separated string values against a list of strings

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, jpa

I have a database table column with comma separated string values like this:

```
id mycolumn
-- --------
1  A
2  A, B
3  A, B, C
```

I can't change this, because it's an old customizer database.

I want to check `mycolumn` against a list of strings:

first query against the list **['A']** should be return the record **1**

second query against the list **['A','B']** should be return records **1,2**

third query against the list **['A','B','C']** should be return records **1,2,3**

I need a sql (postgres) statement and further a java implementation with `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder` and `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate`.

Thank you very much for your hints, Ann

**edit:**
Here my solution for the javax.persitence part:

```
public static void arrayContains(final CriteriaBuilder cb, final List<Predicate> where,
            final Expression<String> expression, final String values) {
        Expression<String> expressionValues = cb.function("string_to_array", String.class, cb.literal(values), cb.literal(", "));
        Expression<String> expressionDb = cb.function("string_to_array", String.class, expression, cb.literal(", "));
        where.add(cb.isTrue(cb.function("arraycontains", Boolean.class, expressionValues, expressionDb)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL use `string_to_array(mycolumn,',')` in the `WHERE` clause with the containment operator `<@`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE string_to_array(mycolumn,',') <@ ARRAY['A','B','C']
```

Keep in mind that you have to create an index that correspond to this condition, in case you're dealing with a large table, e.g. a `GIN` index.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_t_mycolumn_gin ON t USING gin (string_to_array(mycolumn,','));
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=14fb68942cdcc65102e5ea2104592643)

Comment: Very good Jim. Thank you. That is what I need for sql. Now I hope I can develop a solution for javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: Maybe someone can support me?

Comment: @Ann-ChristinLindras I'm pretty sure there is a skilled java developer over there :) it would help if you could add what you've tried so far (java code) and why you specifically need to use these classes. Doing so you'll significantly improve your chances to get a decent answer. The PostgreSQL part you already got from my answer. Cheers

Comment: I have the following java code with `CriteriaBuilder cb, List<Predicate> where`:
`Expression<String> exp = cb.function("string_to_array", String.class, cb.literal("mycolumn"), cb.literal(", "));`
`where.add(cb.isTrue(cb.function("arraycontains", Boolean.class, exp, myList)));`
I don't know how I put myList (e.g. ['A','B','C']) to the cb.function() which extpected as fourth parameter `Expression<T>`.

Comment: @Ann-ChristinLindras add it to your question. Nobody will read it here

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Now I found a solution and I edited the question.

Comment: @Ann-ChristinLindras awesome. cheers and happy coding :)