# Spring data group by with Specification and Paging support

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an "item"-based view, where an item belongs to a container and a container consists of several items. In addition, an item has a location and several items can have the same location.

**database view:**

```
id_item   id_container   id_location   container_name   container_code   amount
'I1'      'C1'           'L1'          'container #01'  'c01'            10
'I2'      'C1'           'L1'          'container #01'  'c01'             5
'I3'      'C1'           'L2'          'container #01'  'c01'            25
'I4'      'C2'           'L3'          'container #02'  'c02'            30
```

I would like to select grouped by container:

entity group by container:

```
@Entity
public class GroupByContainerEntity {
    private String idContainer;
    private String containerName;
    private String containerCode;
    private List<String> locations; // OR private String locations; -> comma separated ids
    private Integer sumAmount;
    private Integer countItems;
}
```

repository:

```
public interface IGroupByContainerRepository extends JpaRepository<GroupByContainerEntity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<GroupByContainerEntity> {
}
```

I need to pass addional specification (e.g. only certain locations and containers) and paging (e.g. sort by container name), therefore a (native) query approach does not work:

```
groupByContainerRepository.findAll(Specification, Pageable)
```

Is there any way to load the data grouped by container (via the spring data repository)?
Specification and Paging support is mandatory.

Comment: Backend pagintation requires the use a unique sorting key. Can you identify one? If you cannot, backend pagination wont' work correctly.

Comment: id_container is unique after grouping.

Comment: You may want to look into https://stackoverflow.com/q/69838836/2739334

Answer (score 2):

Although the `Specification` class is designed to handle **where** clauses, specifying **group by** clause within the `Specification` class also works.

To circumvent the issue that `Specification::toPredicate` method must return a `Predicate` instance, you can create a `Specification` class with **where** clause  equal to `1=1` while declaring **group by** clause within the method, just like the example as follows:

```
public class GroupBySpecification implements Specification<GroupByContainerEntity> {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<GroupByContainerEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        query.groupBy(root.get("containerCode"));
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.literal(1), criteriaBuilder.literal(1));
    }

}
```

Other additional specifications such as locations and container codes can be specified separately:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LocationSpecification implements Specification<GroupByContainerEntity> {

    private final String location;


    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<GroupByContainerEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("idLocation"), location);
    }
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ContainerCodeSpecification implements Specification<GroupByContainerEntity> {

    private final String containerCode;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<GroupByContainerEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("containerCode"), containerCode);
    }

}
```

By doing so, you can reuse the `groupByContainerRepository.findAll(Specification, Pageable)` to fulfill your need. A sample method in the service layer is also given as follows:

```
public Page<GroupByContainerEntity> findAll(ItemSearchParameter params, Pageable pageable) {

    List<Pair<Optional<?>, Function<Object, Specification<GroupByContainerEntity>>>> pairs = List.of(
            Pair.of(params.getLocation(), s -> new LocationSpecification((String) s)),
            Pair.of(params.getContainerCode(), c -> new ContainerCodeSpecification((String) c))
    );

    Specification<GroupByContainerEntity> spec = pairs.stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getFirst().isPresent())
            .map(entry -> entry.getSecond().apply(entry.getFirst().get()))
            .reduce(new GroupBySpecification(), Specification::and);

    return repository.findAll(spec, pageable);
}
```

It is worth to mention that the entity class `GroupByContainerEntity` contains aggregate fields such as **locations**, **sumAmount** and **countItems**. To handle them, we can annotate these fields with `@Formula` and supply the query. Thus, the `GroupByContainerEntity` class is needed to further modify as below:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "item")
public class GroupByContainerEntity {

    @Id
    private String idItem;

    private String idContainer;

    private String idLocation;

    private String containerName;

    private String containerCode;

    @Formula("(GROUP_CONCAT(id_location))")
    private String locations;

    @Formula("(SUM(amount))")
    private Integer sumAmount;

    @Formula("(COUNT(container_code))")
    private Integer countItems;

}
```

I have also pushed the code above to [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/stackoverflow2/java/jpa-specification-group-by-demo). The project uses SQLite as database so you can clone and have a try.

Answer (score 1):

I like a more functional approach:

```
public static <TYPE> Specification<TYPE> create(
    final Function3<Root<TYPE>, AbstractQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder, Predicate> predicate) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
      final Predicate oneEqualsOne = criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.literal(1), 1);
      return criteriaBuilder.and(oneEqualsOne, predicate.apply(root, query, criteriaBuilder));
    };
}

@SafeVarargs
public static <TYPE> Function3<Root<TYPE>, AbstractQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder, Predicate> and(
    final Function3<Root<TYPE>, AbstractQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder, Predicate>... predicates) {
    return and(Arrays.asList(predicates));
}

public static <TYPE> Function3<Root<TYPE>, AbstractQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder, Predicate> and(
  Collection<Function3<Root<TYPE>, AbstractQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder, Predicate>> predicates) {
  return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    // Default 1=1 if List.isEmpty this is needed
    Predicate result = criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.literal(1), 1);
    for (final Function3<Root<TYPE>, AbstractQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder, Predicate> predicate : predicates) {
       result = criteriaBuilder.and(result, predicate.apply(root,criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder));
    }
    return result;
  };
}

public static <TYPE>
  Function3<Root<TYPE>, AbstractQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder, Predicate> stringEqual(
    final String column, final String value) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(column)) {
          return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(column).as(String.class), value);
        } else {
          return criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.literal(1), 1);
        }
     };
}

public static <TYPE> Function3<Root<TYPE>, AbstractQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder, Predicate> orderBy(String column, Sort.Direction direction) {
  return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    if (direction != null
        && StringUtils.isNotBlank(column)
        && criteriaQuery instanceof CriteriaQuery<?>) {
      if (direction.isAscending()) {
          ((CriteriaQuery<?>) criteriaQuery).orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(column)));
      } else {
          ((CriteriaQuery<?>)criteriaQuery).orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(column)));
        }
      }
      return criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.literal(1), 1);
  };
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Specification<FOO> spec = create(
                               and(
                                 stringEqual("name", name), 
                                 stringEqual("lastName",lastName),
                                 orderBy("id", DESC)
                               )
                          );
final PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size/*, Sort.by(direction, order)*/);
repo.findAll(spec,pageRequest);
```

The functional interface can be extended by all kinds of "equals, like, notEquals" in a util kind class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try criteria builder query :

   ```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery < GroupByContainerEntity> cq_GroupByContainerEntity = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(GroupByContainerEntity.class);
    cq_GroupByContainerEntity.select(cq_GroupByContainerEntity);
   ```

   cq_GroupByContainerEntity.groupBy(criteriaBuilder.avg(null)); (use your group by functions)
   cList=sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(cq_GroupByContainerEntity).getResultList();

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface IGroupByContainerRepository extends JpaRepository<GroupByContainerEntity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<GroupByContainerEntity> {
    @Query("select new GroupByContainerVO(a.idItem, count(a.idItem) as countItem) from GroupByContainerEntity a GROUP BY a.idContainer ")
    List<GroupByContainerVO> findGroupByIdContainer();
}
```